# Добавление новых элементов в массив c++

Tags: c++

```
// присвоение 2 раза
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        int len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
        a[len] = i;
        a[len] = i;
        cout << len << " " << a[len] << endl;

    }
}
```

```
output: 0 0\n 1 1\n 2 2\n 3 3\n 4 4\n 5 5\n 6 6\n 7 7\n 8 8\n 9 9
```

```
// присвоение 1 раз
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        int len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
        a[len] = i;
        cout << len << " " << a[len] << endl;

    }
}
```

`output: 0 0\n 1 1\n 2 16061904\n 3 0\n 4 4199367\n 5 0\n 6 0\n 7 0\n 8 69\n 9 0`

Я новичок в плюсах, так что буду благодарен, если кто-то поможет разобраться, в чем тут дело и как добавлять новый элемент в массив используя 1 присвоение, иначе код напоминает анекдот про функцию, которая работает 1 из 2 раз

Comment: Да как ни разбирайся, вы выделили массив из 0 элементов, так что любая запись в него — за пределами массива :) и UB — т.е. все, что угодно. В том числе вот такие вот фокусы... Кстати, половина компиляторов (ну, половина — образно, точно не считал :)) вообще не скомпилирует такое...

Comment: Получается для добавления элементов только vector, а классическим массивом нельзя, правильно я понял?

Comment: Почему нельзя? Задаете массив нужного размера и работаете...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Массивы вида `int a[n]` - статические массивы. Их размер менять нельзя, память под них выделяется во время компиляции. Если вы хотите использовать массивы с меняющимся размером, то используйте  STL класс `std::vector<T>`
Пример использования:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        a.push_back(i); //добавляет число в конец массива
        cout << i << ' ' << a[i] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Подробнее про `vector` можно прочитать [здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/standard-library/vector-class?view=msvc-170) или, если знаете английский, то вот [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).